# Make a dynamic text change when clicking an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a row of four images, each image has some text below. For mobile screens, since each image will be smaller, I want the text to disappear and make one line instead that has some dynamic text so this text will change depending on the image that is active (clicked), meaning I now will show the text only if the image is clicked. How can I achieve this? I have the following so far:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid__col {
  padding-right: 16px
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.icons-grid  {
  img {margin: 0 auto;}
}

.icon-text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
@media (min-width:961px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-l {
    width: 25%;
   } 
 }
  
@media (min-width:641px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-m {
     width: 25%;
   } 
}
  
.grid__col--1-4-s {
  width:25%;
 }
 
.grid_col--end {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid icons-grid ">
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text1' data-text='Text 1'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text2' data-text='Text 2'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text3' data-text='Text3'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s grid__col--end text4' data-text='Te 4'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 4</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You will need javascript to do that functionality, have you tried to do something? Share your JS code so we can help you

Comment: what are you looking for? not able to get it. you want to show your text only when image is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do that would probably be to hide the multiple of texts using media-queries, just as you did in your code (only use `max-width:641px` and modify the `display` parameter).

Aside from that, add a separate `p`, with an opposite media-query that shows it only for the wider displays, and in javascript dynamically control its value.

```
const outputNode = document.querySelector('.icon-text--mobile');

const gridNodes = document.querySelectorAll('.grid__col');
const gridNodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(imageNodes);

gridNodesArray.forEach(function (node, index) {
  const nodeImage = node.querySelector('img');
  const nodeText = node.querySelector('p').innerText;

  nodeImage.addEventListener('click', function () {
    outputNode.innerText = nodeText;
  });
});
```

Comment: what is `imageNodes` ?

Answer (score 1):

js is obviously more efficient here but you can also do this with **pure CSS.**

Set `.icon-text {display: none}` on small screens

Then, using the [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) you can target the specific `.icon-text` after each img to display it when the image is clicked or active

basic example at 641px cut off:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid__col {
  padding-right: 16px padding-left: 16px;
}

img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.icon-text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width:961px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-l {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (min-width:641px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-m {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.grid__col--1-4-s {
  width: 25%;
}

.grid_col--end {
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 641px) {
  .icon-text {
    display: none;
  }
  img:active+.icon-text,
  img:hover+.icon-text,
  img:focus+.icon-text {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #131418;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid icons-grid ">
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text1' data-text='Text 1'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text2' data-text='Text 2'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text3' data-text='Text3'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s grid__col--end text4' data-text='Te 4'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that without the use of JS.
Place a transparent checkbox (opacity: 0) as the first child of every `.grid__col` (Before the image) with the exact same size of the image and then add the following css:

```
.grid__col > input:nth-child(1) {
  width: 140px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
.grid__col > input:nth-child(1):checked+img+.icon-text {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

`.grid__col > input:nth-child(1)` is to assure that the desired input (checkbox) is a child and the first child with the tagname `input` of `.grid__col` so the style we want for the trasparent checkbox goes there.

`.grid__col > input:nth-child(1):checked+img+.icon-text` is to tell the browser that if my desired `checkbox` is `checked` then apply the style to an element with a class name `.icon-text` that is adjacent to an element `img` that is a also adjacent to the checked `checkbox`.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid__col {
  padding-right: 16px
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.icons-grid  {
  img {margin: 0 auto;}
}

.icon-text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
 }
 
@media (min-width:961px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-l {
    width: 25%;
   } 
 }
  
@media (min-width:641px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-m {
     width: 25%;
   } 
}
  
.grid__col--1-4-s {
  width:25%;
 }
 
.grid_col--end {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
 
.grid__col > input:nth-child(1) {
  width: 140px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
.grid__col > input:nth-child(1):checked+img+.icon-text {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid icons-grid ">
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text1' data-text='Text 1'>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text2' data-text='Text 2'>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text3' data-text='Text3'>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s grid__col--end text4' data-text='Te 4'>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 4</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT**
Lets say that you want a single `.icon-text` to appear (That the other ones disappear when you click another image).
if you want to do that with the same technique, then the only thing you have to do is to change the type of the `input` to `radio` and link them with a name "show-text" or something else.
`<input type="checkbox"/>` to `<input type="radio" name="show-text"/>`. There is no need to change the css.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid__col {
  padding-right: 16px
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.icons-grid  {
  img {margin: 0 auto;}
}

.icon-text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
 }
 
@media (min-width:961px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-l {
    width: 25%;
   } 
 }
  
@media (min-width:641px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-m {
     width: 25%;
   } 
}
  
.grid__col--1-4-s {
  width:25%;
 }
 
.grid_col--end {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
 
.grid__col > input:nth-child(1) {
  width: 140px !important;
  height: 100px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
.grid__col > input:nth-child(1):checked+img+.icon-text {
  visibility: visible !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid icons-grid ">
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text1' data-text='Text 1'>
    <input type="radio" name="show-text"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text2' data-text='Text 2'>
   <input type="radio" name="show-text"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text3' data-text='Text3'>
   <input type="radio" name="show-text"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s grid__col--end text4' data-text='Te 4'>
   <input type="radio" name="show-text"/>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 4</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with simple jquery.

```js
$('.grid__col').on('click',function(e){
var text = $(this).data('text');
$(this).find('p').text(text);
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid__col {
  padding-right: 16px
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.icons-grid  {
  img {margin: 0 auto;}
}

.icon-text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 
@media (min-width:961px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-l {
    width: 25%;
   } 
 }
  
@media (min-width:641px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-m {
     width: 25%;
   } 
}
  
.grid__col--1-4-s {
  width:25%;
 }
 
.grid_col--end {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid icons-grid ">
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text1' data-text='Text 1'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text"></p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text2' data-text='Text 2'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text"></p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text3' data-text='Text3'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text"></p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s grid__col--end text4' data-text='Text 4'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text"></p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can do

```
event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
```

fired on click of the image, to display the adjacent text.

Or you can toggle the display:

```
element.style.display = element.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';  //element would be event.target.nextElementSibling
```

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i=0, len=images.length, img; i<len; i++) {
  img = images[i];
  img.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var image = event.target.nextElementSibling;
    image.style.display = image.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
  });
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
}

.grid__col {
  padding-right: 16px
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.icons-grid  {
  img {margin: 0 auto;}
}

.icon-text {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
 }
 
@media (min-width:961px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-l {
    width: 25%;
   }
 }
  
@media (min-width:641px) {
  .grid__col--1-4-m {
     width: 25%;
   } 
}
  
.grid__col--1-4-s {
  width:25%;
 }
 
.grid_col--end {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid icons-grid ">
  <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text1' data-text='Text 1'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text2' data-text='Text 2'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 2</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s text3' data-text='Text3'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 3</p>
   </div>
   <div class='grid__col grid__col--1-4-l grid__col--1-4-m grid__col--1-4-s grid__col--end text4' data-text='Te 4'>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
    <p class="icon-text">Text 4</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/3dud6wt9/)

**Here is the JS code:**

```
$(function() {
    //for mobile do this

  //Hide icon text on page load
  $('p.icon-text').hide();

  //On image click toggle display icon text
  $('img').click(function() {
    //alert('clicked');
    $(this).siblings('p.icon-text').toggle();
  });
})
```